# How do I make a conditional return in WASM?

Tags: webassembly

I am writing a wasm module.

So the code is:

```
(module
  (func (export "someCheck")
    (param $n f64)
    (result i32)

    local.get $n
    f64.const 2
    f64.eq
  )
)
```

This is a simple module that returns the result of $n being equal to 2. If $n is 2 then return 1, otherwise return 0.
Here everything is clear to me.

Here is a similar function written in JavaScript:

```js
const someCheck = (n) => Number(n === 2)
```

But how do I make a conditional return?

Like this, but in wasm:

```js
const someCheck = (n) => {
  if (Number(n === 2))
    return 1;

  // other logic
  return someRez;
}
```

Thanks!

---

**NOTE**
I think someone might need [this table](https://pengowray.github.io/wasm-ops/). She helps me a lot. Especially stack hints

Comment: use opcode 0F: return at any point to leave the current function. If your function has results they would be taken from stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAssembly has the concept of `if`/`else` control structures.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Reference/Control_flow/if...else

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but how do I return if $n === 2 and continue execution if not? Instead of return, just write further in the else block? I would like to avoid excessive nesting

Comment: Are you writing WASM from scratch or do you use something like Rust?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote/accept by the way. I’ll try to provide more details if I can. But I’m not too versed in writing plain WASM/WAT to be honest. (Let’s take it as a learning opportunity.)

Comment: @Alexander I'm as surprised as you are, to find out that wasm doesn't have goto. however you could put a return instruction inside the if.

Comment: @lxg, I'm writing wasm by hand, from scratch. I need to implement one program in the browser, but the standard JavaScript tools are rather ruthless in spending resources where I don't need them. For example, in calculations I need numbers. JavaScript uses float64 when all I need is int2! A small difference, but when storing millions of numbers, the difference begins to show. And about `return`, see my answer to myself, I solved the issue.

Comment: Glad to see you were able to solve it! I would also have thought of the if/then/return construct, but didn’t have the time to try it out before you. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the `0F` operation (`return`, [see table](https://pengowray.github.io/wasm-ops/)).

Here is an example of a function that returns the number 5 if the passed parameter is 2, otherwise it returns the number 10.

```
(module
  (func (export "func")
  (param $n i32)
  (result i32)

  local.get $n
  i32.const 2
  i32.eq

  (if
    (then
      i32.const 5
      return
     )
  )

  i32.const 10
)
```

Here is a JavaScript equivalent

```js
const func = (n) => {
  if (n === 2) {
    return 5;
  }

  return 10;
}
```

A slightly more complex example with multiple if/returns:

```
(module
  (func (export "func")
    (param $n i32)
    (result i32)

    local.get $n
    i32.const 2
    i32.eq

    (if
      (then
        i32.const 1
        return
      )
    )

    local.get $n
    i32.const 3
    i32.eq

    (if
      (then
        i32.const 2
        return
      )
    )

    i32.const 3
  )
)
```

And its JavaScript counterpart:

```js
const func = (n) => {
  if (n === 2) {
    return 1
  }

  if (n === 3) {
    return 2
  }

  return 3
}
```